# When creating a servlet dynamically using the 3.0 spec, how do I register it with an existing statically created filter?

Tags: servlets, jakarta-ee, servlet-filters, servletcontextlistener

There are plenty of examples of how to do this when you create a new servlet and filter together, but I want to use a filter that is already defined in the web.xml.

Comment: Unfortunately it's the other way around - the filter applies to the servlet and you can give the filter a list of servlet "names".  Can you modify the web.xml for the filter?

Comment: No, that's the whole point of the problem

Answer (score 1):

This works (from a ServletListener):

```
ServletContext sc = event.getServletContext();

// dynamically register servlet
ServletRegistration.Dynamic reg = sc.addServlet("MyServlet", MyServlet.class);
reg.addMapping("/MyUrl/*");

// register new servlet with an existing filter
FilterRegistration fr = sc.getFilterRegistration("MyExistingFilterInWebXML");
EnumSet<DispatcherType> all = EnumSet.allOf(DispatcherType.class);
fr.addMappingForServletNames(all, false, "MyServlet");
```

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution - never had to use this but good to know about it.